# How do I modify unified group custom attributes immediately post creation?

Tags: c#, powershell, office365, microsoft-graph-api, azure-functions

I create a unified group using the graph api through a queue-triggered azure function (C#). When created, I want to tag some information on custom attributes and do other exchange-related stuff like hide from GAL. How is this best done?

I have tried using yet another queue-triggered function in order to connect to exchange online with powershell, although I have a hard time getting the credentials right having only clientid, secret and certificate thumbprint in the functions configuration. To run exchange online commandlets it seems like you have to go with actual user credentials (username, password).

I have also explored the possibilities of doing this kind of settings directly from the graph API but it seems limited in this case.

Comment: By chance you can do this in powershell if yes, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/users-and-groups/set-unifiedgroup?view=exchange-ps

Comment: Yes this is the command we normally use to affect these attributes.
The thing is I do not know how to execute the exhange online commandlets like Set-UnifiedGroup in an azure function. So how can that be done or is there even better alternatives for dealing with this post provisioning activities?

Answer (score 1):

I got this working by using an Azure Automation runbook triggered by a webhook.
So after creating the unified group through graph api, a http-call is made to trigger the runbook. The runbook is then utilizing Exchange powershell module to alter group settings.